# Control master audio volume with Siri

Tags: siri, sound-volume

I Can't control my iPad master volume with Siri, and I'm surprised about that.

Is there a way to do this control via Siri?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading about the iPhone 7 preview, it seems that it was only a matter of time

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible and it's an oversight that makes hands free impossible.

What about 'Hey Siri, set volume at 50%', and while they're at it 'Hey Siri, turn speaker on'.

The excuse of volume being too hard are weak.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely a safety feature. If someone was using hands free while driving and changed the volume. It could blast really loud music in your ear and cause you to crash. Possibly injuring yourself and others. This would open up Apple to lawsuits.

Comment: In iOS 10 it is possible.

Answer (score -1):

After asking Siri myself, I've found your answer.

Siri cannot change the volume of your iOS devices.

That much is fact, however my theory regarding why Siri is unable to do change such a simple control is pure speculation; I believe Apple didn't implement this functionality because it would be awkward and hard to use.

Here's the scenario: You're playing music on your iOS device and you want to turn down the volume. You ask Siri to turn down the volume, to which Siri carries out. At this point, one of four things can happen:

1. Your music is still too loud
2. Your music is at the perfect volume for your taste
3. The music becomes too quiet
4. You are listening to music then someone in your house hold says 'Hi Siri, Turn the volume up'. This would then turn your volume up without you telling it to and it could be too loud for you

How would Siri know what volume you want your music to play at? How can she distinguish what would be the perfect volume to play your music even if you gave a general instruction for her to turn it down or up?

Sure, you they could have programmed Siri to lower the volume down one "tick" at a time, but that opens the door to you constantly asking Siri to lower the volume. Same goes with larger increments of volume change in that you couldn't get the volume "just right" using Siri.

Too much uncertainty involved with attempting to provide desired result most likely turned the Siri designers away from implementing the feature.

Comment: it can't do "Tea, Earl Grey, hot" either ;-)

Comment: You forgot another main point. What if someone else (not you) said 'Ok Siri, Turn the volume up'. That would then make your music too loud for you. I have edited your post to include this.

Comment: In iOS 10 it is possible.

Answer (score -1):

Siri could raise or lower the volume slowly and ask for you to signal when to stop by saying stop. Not saying this is easy, but it's the same way to tell someone to stop filling your glass, at your preferred amount, but there would be needed rules or prompts. Another way would be to set volume by say a graduated number set 0-20. When you ask Siri to change volume she 1st says what you are at, and you can say how many "points" to increase or decrease, or set a number. Would take some getting used to but better than nothing. Voice recognition could also differentiate voice, and only allow recognized voice input. You could also set thresholds that wouldn't allow Siri to blow out your speakers with a voice increase limit.

Edited by peer review: Siri responds to such commands with: "Sorry, but I'm not able to change that setting.", hence this answer is completely false.

Comment: In iOS 10 it is possible.